# function on express locals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to write a function to express locals, like this:

```
// user data by id
res.locals.findUser = function(user_id) {
    models.user.findOne({
        '_id': user_id
    }, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        return (user) ? user : 'not found';
    })
}
```

In this case, console logs user's data.. But when I do like this in the client side (with pug js):

```
console.log(findUser('5834cde6e3496b99c37c06d4'))
```

it logs `undefined`

So... isn't possible that write a function in `res.locals`?

Answer (score 0):

Two different programs are two different programs even if they are both written in the same programming language.

You can't call a function (like `findUser`) from the JS program running in the web browser when that function only exists in the program running on the server.

Comment: but i've use functions like this in the pugjs -> [link](https://dotjpg.co/sppfud.png)